# Using Razor syntax for view with two Models of type List<>

Tags: asp.net, razor

I need to implement two Models of type list in a single `.cshtml` page. My Model design is as follows: -

```
public class MainModel
{
    public List<a> a{ get; set; }
    public List<b> b{ get; set; }
}
```

My controller is as follows: -

```
public ActionResult function(List<MainModel> model)
{
    return View("_PartialView", model);
}
```

And my View is as follows: -

```
@model List<Project.Model.MainModel>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].a.somValue, true, null)
}
```

I am not not really sure about how to use `TextBoxFor`. Can someone please point out what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are passing `List<MainModel>` to controller. And `MainModel` has `List<a>` and `List<b>` in it. You are dealing with List of Lists in razor. Do you really need this? You should consider to simplify your model or create a ViewModel for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was able to work out a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Emre Bolat's comment I was able to work out a solution.

I changed my Controller to this: -

```
public ActionResult function(MainModel model)
{
    return View("_PartialView", model);
}
```

And my `Viewpage` to this: -

```
@model Project.Model.MainModel
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); ++i)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.a[i].somValue, true, null)
}
```

Now I'm getting my desired result